# My SSD Partitions are mounting as noexec, in defiance of fstab

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fstab

I'm on 18.04, and my SSD partitions are mounting as "noexec" despite that "exec" is explicitly stated in fstab.  This is happening both with NTFS and EXT4 partitions.

My FStab entries:

LABEL=Speedy /media/dmh/Speedy ext4 rw,nodev,relatime,suid,exec,auto,user,async 0 0

UUID=4A1CA3E81CA3CD6F /media/dmh/Gaming ntfs rw,nodev,relatime,rw,suid,exec,auto,user,async,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0

But findmnt reports:

$ findmnt /media/dmh/Speedy
TARGET            SOURCE         FSTYPE OPTIONS
/media/dmh/Speedy /dev/nvme0n1p2 ext4   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,data=ordered

$ findmnt /media/dmh/Gaming
TARGET            SOURCE         FSTYPE  OPTIONS
/media/dmh/Gaming /dev/nvme0n1p3 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_o

At this point I'm kinda stumped.  Both of these do mount -- After converting to EXT4, I had to remove Speedy's "allow_others" tag to make it mount.

ETA:  Steeldriver's tip was in fact the key, and now my drives are mounting with proper flags.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which the options are specified is significant. From `man mount`:

```
user   Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem.  The name of the
              mounting user is written to the mtab file  (or  to  the  private
              libmount  file  in /run/mount on systems without a regular mtab)
              so that this same user can unmount the filesystem  again.   This
              option  implies  the  options  noexec, nosuid, and nodev (unless
              overridden  by  subsequent  options,  as  in  the  option   line
              user,exec,dev,suid).
```

So, if you want to use both `user` and `exec`, the latter must come **after** the former so that the implied `noexec` of `user` is overridden by an explicit `exec`.