# Permission denied despite having permission

Tags: permissions, mount, filesystem, binary

I did what is described in this [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378363/how-do-i-mount-external-drive-to-the-same-mountpoint-every-time) post, and after that I am not able to run scripts that are on my external ssd, not even after using the `sudo su` command.

[image]

the output of `findmnt -T /media/alexandre/Externo`:

```
root@thinkPad:/media/alexandre/Externo/scrips-automacao-linux# findmnt -T /media/alexandre/Externo 
TARGET                   SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS 
/media/alexandre/Externo /dev/sda1 ext4    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
```

I used the following command:
UUID="3945e28a-a767-4abc-bb45-f4d843fef1b6" /media/alexandre/Externo ext4 defaults,user,auto 0 1

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `findmnt -T /media/alexandre/Externo`

Comment: What is the filesystem on the external SSD?

Comment: Hi, the output of findmnt -T /media/alexandre/Externo

root@thinkPad:/media/alexandre/Externo/scrips-automacao-linux# findmnt -T /media/alexandre/Externo
TARGET                   SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/media/alexandre/Externo /dev/sda1 ext4   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime

Comment: Please add that to your question … It’s easier to format and read … However, you seem to be mounting a filesystem that doesn’t support permissions as EXT4 while it’s not … or you explicitly set the `noexec` flag while you shouldn’t.

Comment: The `user` mount option implies `noexec`

Comment: So, i changed to "UUID="3945e28a-a767-4abc-bb45-f4d843fef1b6" /media/alexandre/Externo ext4 defaults,exec,user,auto 0 0" but don't work

Comment: @AlexandreVieiradeSouza the order in which you specify the `user,exec` options is important - see [My SSD Partitions are mounting as noexec, in defiance of fstab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346887/my-ssd-partitions-are-mounting-as-noexec-in-defiance-of-fstab)

Comment: Thanks everybody, it's working.

"UUID="3945e28a-a767-4abc-bb45-f4d843fef1b6" /media/alexandre/Externo ext4 defaults,user,exec,auto 0 1"